# IOS fade out screen transition after 3 sec

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I am relatively new to iPhone development. I have two view controllers. I want to navigate from one screen to another after 3 sec interval with fade out animation. Can anyone please provide pointers on how to proceed with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need sleep and also you can only sleep when in background process. Seeing as you are animating, you need to do this in the main thread.

This animation will take 3 seconds and sets the view alpha to 0. i.e. fade out. Then when the animation is finished, it fires the completion block. This will push the newView.

```
 [UIView animateWithDuration:3.0 animations:^{
            [self.view setAlpha:0.0];
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:newView animated:YES];
     }];
```

Comment: Thanks mate, but one small fix needed, it throws, incompatible pointer type, sending uiview* to uiviewcontroller*, can you please guide how to proceed with this?

Answer (score 1):

Use sleep to pause execution in ios then push the next view controller on your navigationcontroller.

the fade animation you can do by changing the navigationcontroller animation like explained here: http://www.davidhamrick.com/2011/12/31/Changing-the-UINavigationController-animation-style.html

Comment: what do you think..? this is An answer @jonas..?

Comment: @NitinGohel An anwser is still better than no answer? i can't find your solution

Comment: i talking about put only one line of answer is not an asnwer plese give proper solution of relevant question. its good for you and asker to.now you are going to  edited answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Write a new method where you write your navigation code and from your button action or where you are writing the present navigation code use "performSelector: withObject: afterDelay:" method with delay of 3 and object as nil.

Answer (score 0):

For `UIViewController`s you can use:

`transitionFromViewController:toViewController:duration:options:animations:completion:`

Or `transitionWithView:duration:options:animations:completion:` for `UIView`s.